# Best method for intersecting a time list with a time range list

Tags: python

Basically what I have is this:

```
secondData = [["8:33:00", 5], ["8:33:01", 3], ...] # and so forth
minuteData = [["8:33:00", 6], ["8:34:00", 5], ...] # and so forth
```

Now pretend like the time is an actual datetime object

What I want to do is find the most efficient method for iterating through the minute data and getting all the contained second data for that minute. e.g. if I have "8:34:00" I want "8:34.00".."8:34:59". Is there an easy way to make a list filter for this or something?

I should note that the lists are arranged in order of time, however there might be missing second data. I might only have 33 data points for the minute 9:58 for example.

Comment: couldnt you just join the 8:33:00 into 833.00 and convert it to a float then you could just filter against a float range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html).

```
from bisect import bisect_left
secondData[bisect_left(secondData, "8:33:00"):bisect_left(secondData, "8:34:00")]
```

This will give you the slice of `secondData` for the half-open interval ["8:33:00".."8:34:00").